# 2007 Designer or Infopath

Tags: list, infopath, custom-form, custom

I Need to create a form that needs to be searchable.  Do I create it in Designer, InfoPath or just create a list?  I do need the information to be searchable.

The objective is to create a search box and search the information that was entered into the custom form that was created.  They want to be able to pull up information fast when fielding customer calls.

Comment: That is very dependent on your other needs than searchability, can you update the question with more information about your objective? :)

Answer (score 0):

All of the above.

You can use InfoPath, a list, or a list form customized in SharePoint Designer.  The SharePoint search indexer will crawl all of it and make it searchable.  Just check the Indexing Options on your list settings page to ensure the data you want to be indexed is included.

Comment: Thank you!  I think the list is probably the easiest for me right now, but maybe I could try infoPath.  I need a search box to only search the information that will be entered into the form.  Would using All of the Above help me achieve this?

Comment: If you are wanting to search the content of everything in the list, you can do it with a search scope.  If you are wanting to search only the content on the current page (i.e. when viewing the form) you can do it on a custom SharePoint Designer for with some jQuery: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/search-on-this-page-using-jquery.aspx